# Examples of why we need initialization blocks

Tags: java, initialization, block

I was going through this topics:

1. [In what order do static initializer blocks in Java run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007666/in-what-order-do-static-initializer-blocks-in-java-run)
2. [Java Static Initialization Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058766/java-initialization-order)

And I don't understand if we have a constructors, where we can put some logic, such as dealing with exceptional situations, why we need initialization blocks, which code we can also move to constructor ?

If the answer is that in some cases we need to initialize some resources before constructor runs would you help me with some examples, so I could fully see the picture.

Comment: I don't have examples off the top of my head, so this is a comment. Initialization blocks are nice if you don't want to duplicate work across constructors. Static initialization blocks are nice if you want to do more complex work when initializing static variables.

Comment: @user3580294 you may call another constructor to avoid putting logic in initialization block.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza But there may be situation where we have `constructor(String)` `constructor(int)` and this constructors could be setting up instance in different ways, so they shouldn't be mixed.

Comment: @Pshemo use builder pattern for such cases.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You are right, that would be better. I was just giving general idea of where initialization blocks could be used, not saying that they must be used :).

Comment: @Pshemo well, I find your example as a good example to not use initialization blocks but instead builder pattern :P

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am starting to wander why do we actually need initialization blocks (not static ones, they can be useful for instance in [enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883646/java-enum-methods/18883717#18883717))

Comment: @Pshemo: double brace initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why we need initialization blocks

For instance initialization blocks, I can only think on two cases:

1. When creating an anonymous class:

   ```
   Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
       int x;
       //initialization block here
       {
           //IMO this is such odd design, it would be better to not
           //create this as an anonymous class
           x = outerClassInstance.someMethod();
       }
       @Override
       public void run() {
           //write the logic here...
       }
   };
   ```
2. When using double brace initialization (if the class is not marked `final`):

   ```
   List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>() {
       {
           add("Hello");
           add("world");
       }
   };
   System.out.println(stringlist);
   //prints [Hello, world]
   ```

For static initialization blocks, there are two cases:

1. When defining the data for a `static` field. This is covered in [@ChrisThompson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23899183/1065197).
2. When initializing a constant (`static final`) field from an external source, like the result of some computation.

   ```
   class Foo {
       public static final boolean DEBUG;
       static {
           DEBUG = getDebugMode();
       }
       private static boolean getDebugMode() {
           //code to open a properties file, read the DEBUG property
           //and return the value
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

One example of a time when you'd use (and I have used) static initialization blocks is to initialize a collection of elements.  For example, if I have some set of parsers that are stored in a static map:

```
 private static Map<String, Parser> parsers = new HashMap<String, Parser>();
```

I may use a static initialization block to populate the members of this map:

```
static {
  parsers.put("node", new NodeParser());
  parsers.put("tree", new TreeParser());
  parsers.put("leaf", new LeafParser());
  //etc.
}
```

I would do this because I want the map to be static rather than part of a particular object, or if I only want there to be one of these maps (maybe I only need one).

The difference between this and a constructor is the constructor is called at object *instantiation* whereas the static initialization block will be called when the class is *loaded*.

That is, if you call

```
MyClass.parsers.get("node");
```

The `MyClass` constructor is never called so if you waited to initialize the `parsers` map until the constructor, the above call would return null.

Comment: The best example I could find for `static` initializers is when a constant variable must be retrieved from a configuration file and must be kept as constant.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yeah, that's a GREAT use of a static initializer