# Switch statement not working in Java with enum

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I created an enum like so

```
public enum Direction {
    NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST, NORTHWEST, NORTHEAST, SOUTHWEST, SOUTHEAST
}
```

then I try to use it in a switch statement

```
 Direction direction = Direction.NORTH;
    switch(direction){
    NORTH:
        System.out.println("Syntax error on token {, case expected after this token");
        break;
    }
```

I am getting the error I put in the println...

Comment: case NORTH: .....

Comment: 3 upvotes for zero research effort? Ok...

Comment: @Tom 1 downvote for envy effort? Ok... Rule #1 if you have a problem even if minor and you think it is a silly problem the truth is many people will have that same problem.

Comment: @CodeCamper And? Even if they have same problem, they _could_ be able to spent 5 seconds to research and they are done with it.

Comment: @Tom I spent 10 seconds but I couldn't see the problem because the all capitals. I had other enum code with case but for something reason my eyes tricked me with the capital letters. Also I learned something new because of the answer talking about Enum Methods to avoid this all together.

Answer (score 5):

You miss the `case` keyword.

```
switch(direction){
case NORTH:
    System.out.println("Syntax error on token {, case expected after this token");
    break;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/MF7IsO)

Answer (score 3):

While not directly answering the question, I would suggest adding a method to the enum ([Java Enum Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883646/java-enum-methods)) and calling the method instead. This would make it cleaner if and when we add a new enum type. We don't have to make modifications to the switch case, just add the implementation for the newly added enum type.