# Can I do a switch statement with Strings with this parameter?

Tags: java, switch-statement

So I need to implement a switch statement that is used when given a command.  The commands are like "end", or "B".  However, one of the commands is setup like "S1" or "S6", the int after referring to a certain thing later in the program.  Can I do a switch statement for all the other commands, and also the "S" + int one at the same time?  Meaning it will go to that section of the switch statement that starts with "S", regardless of the number afterwards?

```
switch(command) {
    case "B":
        ....
        break;
    case "S" + %d (???):  // I know this won't work, just trying to convey the idea
        ....
        break;
}
```

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: You'd have to handle that in `default:`.

Comment: Might be able to get away with it using the default case (where no other case was matched) and then performing a regex check there.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 7, the case labels in a `switch` statement can be `String`s.  Of course, then the `switch` expression must also be a `String`.  The case labels must be *constant* `String`s, however, so nothing of the form `"S" + %d (???)` or anything much like it is supported.

If you only have one special case command to deal with, however, then perhaps you can handle it in the `default` case:

```
switch(command) {
    case "B":
        ....
        break;
    case "FOO":
        // ...
        break;
    default:
        if (command.startsWith("S")) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // whatever ...
        }
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. If this sort of switch is the correct way to go (and if often isn't; you may want to see how rich enums can help in this situation), then you might try this:

```
switch (command.charAt(0)) {
    case 'B':
        ....
        break;
    case 'S':
        switch (command.chatAt(1)) {
            case '0':
                ....
                break;
        }
        ....
        break;
}
```

Adding methods to enums, which will likely result in more readable application code in this situation, is explained [in the Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).  There's a few good examples here on Stack Overflow; check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18883646/3195526).

As an example:

```
public enum CommandType {
    B {
        @Override
        public Object doStuff() {
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
    S1 {
        @Override
        public Object doStuff() {
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
    S6 {
        @Override
        public Object doStuff() {
            ...
        }
    }

    public abstract Object doStuff();
};
```

(Of course, you could put all the logic in the base `doStuff()` and forget about overriding it for each enum value, if that's better in your case.)

Then your application code can do something like

```
Enum.valueOf(CommandType.class, command).doStuff();
```

Comment: You mean `command.charAt(0)` rather than `command[0]`, right? :)