# Elegant way of returning opposite enum

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum for which each element has an opposite. I'd like an elegant way to encapsulate this inside each element of the enum. My preferred options is not legal as it uses forward references.

```
enum Direction {
    NORTH(SOUTH), SOUTH(NORTH), EAST(WEST), WEST(EAST);

    private final Direction opposite;

    Direction(Direction opposite) {
        this.opposite = opposite;
    }

    public Direction getOpposite() {
        return opposite;
    }
}
```

Using a supplier is also illegal.

```
enum Direction {
    NORTH(() -> SOUTH), SOUTH(() -> NORTH), EAST(() -> WEST), WEST(() -> EAST);

    private final Supplier<Direction> opposite;

    Direction(Supplier<Direction> opposite) {
        this.opposite = opposite;
    }

    public Direction getOpposite() {
        return opposite.get();
    }
}
```

Which leaves me with overriding the method:

```
enum Direction {
    NORTH{
        public Direction getOpposite() {
            return SOUTH;
        }
    }, 
    SOUTH{
        public Direction getOpposite() {
            return NORTH;
        }
    }, 
    EAST{
        public Direction getOpposite() {
            return WEST;
        }
    }, 
    WEST{
        public Direction getOpposite() {
            return EAST;
        }
    };

    public abstract Direction getOpposite();
}
```

Using a switch:

```
enum Direction {
    NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST;

    public Direction getOpposite() {
        return switch(this) {
            case NORTH -> SOUTH;
            case SOUTH -> NORTH;
            case EAST -> WEST;
            case WEST -> EAST;
        }
    }
}
```

Or a map:

```
enum Direction {
    NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST;

    private static final Map<Direction,Direction> OPPOSITES =
        Map.of(NORTH, SOUTH, SOUTH, NORTH, EAST, WEST, WEST, EAST);

    public Direction getOpposite() {
        OPPOSITES.get(this);
    }
}
```

None of the alternatives are as straightforward or readable as just listing the opposite as an argument.

Is there an elegant way to avoid the forward reference issue?

Comment: Why not use multiole or statement inside `if..else`??

Comment: Another alternative is to use `static{..}` initialization block to set up enum values after they will already exist like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18883717

Comment: The map option isn't even bad. The lookup time is great too. The question is kind of arbitrary and subjective since the criteria is `elegant`, whatever that means.

Comment: Personally I would use the Map and provide a function like public static Direction#inverse(Direction) and use the private static final Map and use the `guava` ImmutableMap as the Map implementation.

Comment: The advantage of a `switch` statement over a map is that if you later add another enum value, the compiler will tell you if you forget to update the cases. That won't happen with a map.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is a little better:

```
enum Direction {
    NORTH("SOUTH"), SOUTH("NORTH"), EAST("WEST"), WEST("EAST");

    private final String opposite;

    Direction(String opposite) {
        this.opposite = opposite;
    }

    public Direction getOpposite() {
        return Direction.valueOf(opposite);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change the order:

```java
enum Direction {
    NORTH, EAST, WEST, SOUTH:
    ...
}
```

And use `Direction.values()`:

```java
public Direction opposite() {
    Direction[] array = values();

    return array[(ordinal() + 2) % array.length];
}
```

Comment: Clever option, but why that over `values()`?

Comment: I prefer `values()` -- just scanned the javadoc too quickly.  Changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Relying on order in an enum seems... fragile? TBH I'd prefer the Map approach.

Comment: I'm not sure I disagree but a developer needs to examine any Enum that implements instance methods before blindly adding another member